# IE hanging, using 100% of the CPU

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a web application, which in the course of a normal interaction, hangs IE. By "IE being hung", I mean that IE doesn't respond anymore and using 100% of the CPU. The only to get out of this state is to kill the IE process. About the app:

- It loads only one page in the browser, communicates with a server with Ajax queries, and updates the DOM.
- I can reproduce this with both IE6 and IE7, but not Firefox or Safari.

I am wondering if anyone has seen this already, and if there are a few known cases that can get IE into this hung / using 100% of the CPU state.

Comment: Hi, Is this page available on the Internet to have a look? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an app which was create for a client and which isn't public.

Comment: Maybe if you could post some of the HTML/JavaScript of the page? Also, can you give us information the memory usage of the page? Is it high? Does it climb?

Comment: The page is quite big. There is about 1 MB of HTML, 600 KB of JavaScript (minimized, combined in one file). When loading the page, IE7 mem usage increases by 20 MB. When using the page, it increases by another 40 MB. In increases another 50 MB before it hangs.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe Sorry, because this is an application created for a client, I can't share much here. I'd have to create a reproducible test case which doesn't include any of the code, which seems close to impossible :).

Comment: Alessandro, IE is very bad (slow) at locating elements in the DOM using XPATH, and quite bad at manipulating the DOM (adding sub-nodes.)  What kinds of ops is your AJAX performing on the DOM (both read & write?)

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe Yes, it is indeed :).

Comment: @Vlad Romascanu, it is performing all kind of operations, including massive updates of the page (yes read and write).

Comment: Alessandro, did you ever solve this problem? We are running into something very very similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use WinDbg, http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/

Attach it to the IE process that has the problem.

The .symfix+ command will set your symbol path to point to the Microsoft symbol server and cache the debug symbols locally.

The !runaway command will enumerate all the stacks in the process and tell you which one is going berserk.

If you're lucky, you may see something recognizable, such as a regex replacement at the top of the stack. Or perhaps the layout engine has gone into an infinite loop. Both of these have happened to me in the past.

If the callstack doesn't make sense, use 'g' to make the process go, wait a few seconds, hit Ctrl+Break, then try !runaway again.

Once you've got the symbols locally, you can also use SysInternals' Process Explorer to look at a process's stacks. Configure the Symbols option in Process Explorer to point to your local symbol cache, something like c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows\sym.

Comment: @George V. Reilly, This is a great tip. I'll definitely have to try this one out.

Comment: @George V. Reilly, BTW, are you the buy on the picture of that Microsoft site you recommended? ;)

Comment: Heh. Nope. But I am one of the pasty white guys with beards and glasses on the cover of "Beginning ATL COM Programming".

Comment: @George, :). So we are in good company; I am the guy on the right on this Professional XML book: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0471777773.html

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the script debugger (via Visual Studio, in my case), and see what is causing it.

Most likely it's a javascript running an infinite loop, or just looping too fast for what needs to be done per ajax request.

Comment: But if this is what is happening, shouldn't IE suggest to stop running the script after a certain amount of time? At least I am used to see this message in IE when I write an infinite loop. Are there cases where IE can't detect a script running for a long time?

Comment: @Alessandro-Vernet, that error only occurs in situations. You're right, it can be helpful, but there are a large class of situations that can occur where you won't get that message.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe Interesting, I didn't know that infinite loops could get IE to hang. Thanks for that information. I'll try to follow the advice from another user who suggested I test this with IE8 and use the IE8 tools to debug this.

Comment: I have seen FF do this, but never IE. The answer from George Reilly sounds promising.

Comment: It depends where it's stuck. It could be in the JavaScript engine. It could be in the HTML layout engine or some other native code, in which case the script debugger will not help. The WinDbg trick that I gave will help pinpoint what's happening.

Comment: George, it is not happening in the JavaScript engine. I used your method to get stack traces, and have posted them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576349/ie-hanging-with-100-cpu-got-stack-trace

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tracing the problem? If the problem also happens in IE8 you could use console.log commands and their awesome new debugger/dev tool that's built in. Otherwise use the old dev toolbar for IE or alerts. Try to reduce the problem and then file a bug (and paste the code here please).

Comment: The code has been sprinkled with console.log() but that hasn't helped. I also have stack traces, which you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576349/ie-hanging-with-100-cpu-got-stack-trace